# C# open another application take an action within other application

Tags: c#

I'm very new to C#, what I'm trying to understand if it's possible to open another application, in this example Toad Data Point and then take an action within that application.   What I'm hoping to accomplish is open Toad Data Point and then kick off an Automation Script.  The automation script is the TAS file.  You should be able to kick off the automation script by hitting f5 while in the application.  Any wisdom is greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process toad = new Process();
        toad.StartInfo.FileName = @"T:\InterTeam\Decision-Support\AHS\SQL\Test Scripts\TCC ACO Test Streamline\Entity Automation Scripts\EntityX TCC 2015.tas";
        toad.Start();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does TOAD have a commandline interface? In C#, you can run an exe using the Process object and pass arguments (also part of StartInfo). You'd need FileName to point to the TOAD exe and check what parameters TOAD expects if it has a commandline interface (or it might be worth looking into whether or not it has a programming API)..

Comment: if windows has a registered program to handle the .tas file, then you should be able to do something like this.  Otherwise, if it handles a command line parameter as above, otherwise.... gets more complicated depending on what TOAD is

Answer (score 0):

Ok,if you want to start another application,you can try to use 'cmd.exe'.What's more,'StartInfo' has other arguments,if you want to start your file,you can do this:

```
 Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"T:\InterTeam\Decision-Support\AHS\SQL\Test Scripts\TCC ACO Test Streamline\Entity Automation Scripts\";
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "EntityX TCC 2015.tas";
            process.Start();
```